# Facing issue while creating Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

Fail to create archetype.quickstart while creating maven project.

[image]

I checked my internet connectivity it's stable but still facing it.Can anyone solve this problem.
I don't know it would be about repository configuration may be,but dont know how to do!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is failing because on the screenshot I see a download of artifacts which can take some time?

Comment: Downloading the archetype is going forever waiting state.

Comment: Build your project or generating on the plain command line instead of working inside your IDE...